# Buddypress registration page hangs

Tags: buddypress, user-registration

Installed fresh set of wordpress and buddypress. Enabled user registration.

Trying to register user. But the page hangs and if seen in Network tab of chrome, the status shown is pending waiting for the response from the server.

But in wp_users, this user record is created successfully. The only issue is, the page hangs and takes the user to no where.

Is this supposed to be an issue with buddypress / some settings that I am missing? This is the issue in IE, Firefox & chrome (that I tried)

Below are the environment details

Wordpress version 3.6

Buddypress version 1.8.1

Wamp server

Any kind of help / suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-installed the wamp server with the latest one. This fixed the issue. Looks like this was the issue with Apache.